# How to resolve NoClassDefFoundError for MobileAds class for Godot-Android plugin?

Tags: java, android, gdscript, godot4

### Problem

I'm trying to create a [simple Godot-Android plugin](https://github.com/starkindustries/godot-android-plugin-demo/tree/admob-demo) that integrates the `MobileAds` class. However, my app keeps crashing with this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/MobileAds; at [...] HelloWorld.getHello() (HelloWorld.java:48)

### Overview

I started with this working [HelloWorld plugin demo](https://github.com/starkindustries/godot-android-plugin-demo/tree/main) as a baseline. Then I added the line `MobileAds.initialize(activity);` plus a few log statements.

```
// HelloWorld.java
public class HelloWorld extends GodotPlugin {

    // ...

    @UsedByGodot
    public String getHello() {
        Log.d(TAG, "logging getHello()..");
        Activity activity = this.getActivity();
        Log.d(TAG, "this.getActivity() completed..");
        if (activity != null) {
            MobileAds.initialize(activity);  // <== crash occurs here (HelloWorld.java:48)
            Log.d(TAG, "MobileAds initialized!");
        }
        return "Helllooooo Woooorrrllldd!!";
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

The function `getHello()` gets called from the `HelloWorld.gd` script:

```
func _ready():
    helloworld = Engine.get_singleton("HelloWorld")
    helloworld.connect("testSignal", self.on_testSignal)
    print(helloworld.getHello())
```

I build the Android project and copy the archive file from the Android project over to Godot:

```
$ cp android-studio-project/app/build/outputs/aar/app-debug.aar godot-project/android/plugins/
```

I then run the game on my Android device (Pixel 6a).

**Expected behavior:** it does not crash and initializes `MobileAds`.

**Actual behavior:** it crashes with error above.

I have tested very [similar code](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/main/kotlin/admob/InterstitialExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/interstitialexample/MainActivity.kt#L237C15-L237C25) on an Android only project (not a Godot plugin) and `MobileAds` works perfectly fine.

What could be the issue?

### Details

- Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2
- Godot v4.1.2.stable.official [399c9dc39]
- Pixel 6a, Android 14
- Source code: https://github.com/starkindustries/godot-android-plugin-demo/tree/admob-demo
- Complete error dump: https://github.com/starkindustries/godot-android-plugin-demo/issues/1
- Full stack trace:

```
--------- beginning of crash
2023-11-03 22:36:34.317  1704-1763  worlddemoplugin         org...otengine.helloworlddemoplugin  A  runtime.cc:699] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallVoidMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/MobileAds;
    runtime.cc:699]   at java.lang.String com.s6industries.myapplication.HelloWorld.getHello() (HelloWorld.java:48)
    runtime.cc:699]   at boolean org.godotengine.godot.GodotLib.step() (GodotLib.java:-2)
    runtime.cc:699]   at void org.godotengine.godot.vulkan.VkRenderer.onVkDrawFrame() (VkRenderer.kt:83)
    runtime.cc:699]   at void org.godotengine.godot.vulkan.VkThread.run() (VkThread.kt:224)
    runtime.cc:699] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~C4aYRPkycL058nK3xa16uA==/org.godotengine.helloworlddemoplugin-ASaTu85QwxSMEMQUObHI8A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~C4aYRPkycL058nK3xa16uA==/org.godotengine.helloworlddemoplugin-ASaTu85QwxSMEMQUObHI8A==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~C4aYRPkycL058nK3xa16uA==/org.godotengine.helloworlddemoplugin-ASaTu85QwxSMEMQUObHI8A==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
    runtime.cc:699]   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
    runtime.cc:699]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
    runtime.cc:699]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
    runtime.cc:699]   at java.lang.String com.s6industries.myapplication.HelloWorld.getHello() (HelloWorld.java:48)
    runtime.cc:699]   at boolean org.godotengine.godot.GodotLib.step() (GodotLib.java:-2)
    runtime.cc:699]   at void org.godotengine.godot.vulkan.VkRenderer.onVkDrawFrame() (VkRenderer.kt:83)
    runtime.cc:699]   at void org.godotengine.godot.vulkan.VkThread.run() (VkThread.kt:224)
    runtime.cc:699] 
    runtime.cc:699]     in call to CallVoidMethodV
    runtime.cc:699]     from boolean org.godotengine.godot.GodotLib.step()
```

### Troubleshooting Steps Taken

- Verified that commenting out line 48 causes the app to run normally.
- Made sure to include the implementation for ads in my [build.gradle](https://github.com/starkindustries/godot-android-plugin-demo/blob/admob-demo/android-studio-project/app/build.gradle.kts): `implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:22.5.0")`
- Verified the import: `import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;`
- Tried different ads version: `implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.4.0")`
- Inspected `classes.jar` in the aar file:

```
$ jar tf classes.jar 
com/
com/s6industries/
com/s6industries/myapplication/
com/s6industries/myapplication/HelloWorld.class
```